# How to close the window after a sql file has finished running

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a script that I turned into an exe that connects to an oracle database, then runs a sql script. after the script is done, the window stays open. I have tried a few commands and the sql> stays there. Thanks!

```
ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Comment: What commands did you try?

Comment: EXIT, as the final command in the SQL script, might help.

Comment: How did you turn a script into an executable?  If the executable is opening a window, invoking `SQL*Plus`, and passing in the .sql script, the script would need to close the `SQL*Plus` session (via `exit`) and the executable would need to close the window it opened.

Comment: I tried exit. I have sqlplus username/password@//computername:1521/database @C:\Scripts\Script2.sql

Comment: ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK; is in my .sql script. I tried exit at the end of the sql script

Answer (score 1):

Edit your C:\Scripts\Script2.sql file and add an `exit` statement at the end on a line by itself.

You may need to ensure that the prior command is correctly terminated with a `;` or a `/` character on a line by itself.

```
ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
exit
```

Comment: Enter value for user_name: jbagwell
old   1: ALTER USER &user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK
new   1: ALTER USER jbagwell ACCOUNT UNLOCK

User altered.

SQL>      ***this is all that happens after exit***

Comment: it does of course exit if I type exit after the command has ran.

Comment: Are you calling the sql script from some other OS script like a batch file? Are you certain you edited the correct file?

Comment: Yes I am calling it from a bat file. and yes I did it both ways like you suggested

Comment: is there some sore of way to force it like in powershell?

Comment: @JordanBagwell - [as noted on a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55262230/266304), the `.sql` file being run is on your local machine, so you have to add the exit to that file - not to the same file on the remote server.

Comment: @Alex Poole that was the issue. I am very new to sql. I did very little at my last position, but my new one is only sql based. I was unaware when taking the job. Thanks so much for the help.